# composition vs MI example

Tags: c++, wrapper, multiple-inheritance, abstraction

I have come across this library, [orocos bfl](http://www.orocos.org/bfl). It uses external matrix libraries, and in wrapping them, they use multi-inheritence; such as

```
class Matrix: public Matrix_Wrapper, public Boost::Matrix
{
 //some implementation
}
```

as oppose to composition

Is there a good reason (performance, etc), or is it just a bad piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason for using MI here. This way, the `Matrix` class can be used in algorithms that are specific to orocos bfl, but it also can still be used in algorithms that expect matrices of the library that orocos bfl uses for its implementation.

The orocos library can use different libraries to provide it with a basic matrix implementation, so the algorithms provided by orocos can't be tied to one particular matrix interface.
At the same time, users of the orocos library will most likely need additional algorithms to operate on the matrices they use with the orocos libraries.
By using multiple inheritance, the orocos library can be treated as an extension to one of several underlying matrix libraries.

Comment: But if I have to keep in mind which wrapper implementation I have used in the set up than in a sense I have missed the point of abstraction.


Secondly, isn't there a good chance for name resolution conflict. eg `size()`, `rowsCount()` `operator [] (int)` etc, will almost definitely be declared in both parents

Comment: @aiao: I doubt that abstraction was a design goal here. Rather an application of the adapter pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). As for the second point, yes that risk exists but can be worked around if you are careful. And C++ provides the possibility to resolve such conflicts.